# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape' has no attribute 'scalar'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train DNNClassifier but when i try to train the model i keep running into this 
issue called

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape' has no attribute 'scalar'**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')



feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[784])]

feature_columns

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist['data'] , mnist['target'])

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[300, 100], n_classes=10,
                                             feature_columns=feature_columns)


def input_train_fn(X,y):
    features = {'x':tf.convert_to_tensor(X)}
    return features, y.reshape((-1,1)).astype(int)


classifier.train(input_fn=lambda : input_train_fn(X_train, y_train), steps=100000)
```

last line throws following error:-

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape' has no attribute 'scalar'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading your tensorflow and tensorflow-estimator might help.

I found this commit in Github tf-estimator repository (https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/commit/561b3f95d4f9041cb7a2fbbfdc94efee16413725#diff-a815f16c6f90bfe736d98b8c99a7c2fcL337).

Answer (score 1):

**The code you use is depreciated**

You need to adjust the tensor_shape you use.

```
# depreciated
# tensor_shape.scalar()

# running
tensor_shape.TensorShape([])
```